# Visual Studio Recovery Backup Location and Freezing

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, networking, visual-studio-2012

We find that Visual Studio hangs frequently if our code is stored on a network drive. Moving to to the local drive fixed this.

However, now we are using the Modeller, it saves recover information to

H:\Visual Studio 2012\Backup Files

and there seems no option to change that.

As a result, it frequently hangs with "Saving auto recovery information".  It does eventually complete, but it takes minutes to do so.

Our network drives work fine for other programs etc.

Has anyone else seen this and found a solution?  Is the location a registry setting?

Answer (score 4):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> AutoRecover. Here you'll find AutoRecover information every 5 min change it accordingly as per your need.